# ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] while using Selenium in Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to launch Firefox and land to my desired website. But I was getting an error message "ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]". I tried using the interactive shell and I was able to launch the browser, except that the error showed up when I try to specify a website. Please see the code below

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> browser.get('http://google.com') --> this part is the trouble
```

I already tried to check my internet options and it is set to automatic. I'm not sure if this maybe caused by a firewall or some admin rights for this to get going.Please take note that I am using an admin account for this project. Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I figured it out. The browser must not be closed after being launched in the interactive shell. All works perfectly fine now. Considered this ticket closed!

Comment: If the browser must not be closed while launching in the shell, was your script able to run the webdriver's get command without issues despite the browser not being open at the time it was run? I am having a similar issue with chrome.